# i18next - Language switch is not working properly

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I created a language switcher with the i18next js-solution. Everytime i click on the link to change the language, the new language is getting displayed for a second - then the website switches back to the language which is set in the init function.

Does anybody know how I can solve it? I think it has something to do with the `document(ready)` function, but when i remove this - nothing is working :/

Thank you!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18next-1.7.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.i18n.init(
        {
          lng: 'en-US'
        },
        function(t) {
        // translate nav
        $(".nav").i18n();
      });

      $('.changeLng').click(function() {
        $.i18n.setLng("de-DE", function(t) {
          $(".nav").i18n();
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="index.html?setLng=de-DE" class="changeLng">change to de</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-i18n="nav.home"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18next-1.7.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.i18n.init(
        {
          lng: 'en-US'
        },
        function(t) {
        // translate nav
        $(".nav").i18n();
      });

      $('.changeLng').click(function() {
        $.i18n.setLng("de-DE", function(t) {
          $(".nav").i18n();
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="changeLng">change to de</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-i18n="nav.home"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you click the link in your version you are reloading the page and the language gets set to 'en-US' again (as the document.ready function gets called again). In this version the page is not reloaded and therefore the language change sticks about.